# Graph representation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm not familiar with matplotlib and networkx and I've been using the traditional method of representing graph using adjacency matrix as shown by following code.

```
import queue 
# A class to represent a graph object
class Graph:
    # Constructor to construct a graph
    def __init__(self, edges, n, disconnected = False, Nodes = None):
        # A list of lists to represent an adjacency list
        
        self.adjList = [None] * n 
        
        # allocate memory for the adjacency list
        for i in range(n):
            self.adjList[i] = []
        # add edges to the directed graph
        if disconnected:
          
          self.adjList.insert(0, Nodes)
        for (src, dest, weight) in edges:
            # allocate node in adjacency list from src to dest
            if(disconnected):
                self.adjList[src+1].append((dest+1, weight))
            else:
              self.adjList[src].append((dest, weight))

# Function to print adjacency list representation of a graph
def printGraph(graph,n):
    for src in range(len(graph.adjList)):
        # print current vertex and all its neighboring vertices
        for (dest, weight) in graph.adjList[src]:
            new_graph[src].append(dest)
            print(f'({src} —> {dest}, {weight}) ', end='')
        print()
# construct a graph from a given list of edges
graph = Graph(data.edges, data.tasks)
new_graph = [[] for i in range(data.tasks)]
# print adjacency list representation of the graph
printGraph(graph,data.tasks)
```

Is there a way I can get an pictorial representation of the same graph without changing my original code?

Comment: Consider using the GraphViz graph layout and rendering suite. Iirc there are python bindings available.

Comment: @collapsar please tell me how can I do that

Comment: Please show the steps for clarification @collapsar